# Where should apex:pageMessages be placed in a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, pagemessages

I have an issue where my apex:pageMessages does not appear in the visualforce page even though i have that tag on the top of the page.

Now, i tried placing the apex:pagemessages component just below the apex:pageBlock and it started working fine. Before that, apex:pageMessages was just above the apex:pageBlock tag.

I am very confused now that where we need to place the apex:paeMessages component in a visualforce page?

Does the placement of it really matters and affects the rendering of it? Please clarify.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When the Ajax requests happen and then the controller is back from the server to client its important to rerender apex:pagemessages tag as well .

Alternatively we have Id attribute to pagemessage and in ReRender tag specify Id as well of the Pagemessage tag

Comment: Thanks @Mohit. I didnt try rerendering apex:pageMessages before. I am going to try it now.